# Wiping System and Starting Again

Tags: system

I have downloaded a bad version of wine and so my applications no longer work. I am finding it hard to locate all the programs that I downloaded using it and thought that it would be easier to just wipe my system and start again. Is there a simple way of doing this?

I don't have a disc drive so if there is an option to do this from USB that would be great.

Thanks for any help

Comment: @the_Seppi I have edited to ask if there is an option that doesn't include a cd drive

Comment: Just use the live USB instead then...

Comment: Just delete the c directory for wine and reinstall wine. Put more information about your problem if that does not work please.

Comment: @Tim It's just a bunch files, is there one that I should run or anything?

Comment: Restart and set the bios to boot from usb.

Comment: @Tim How do I set the BIOS in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just the same as windows - how did you first install with cd? Restart, open bios with either `del` or `F2` or `F12` (it will say when it boots up). Then chose under `boot order` to boot with `USB` or `removable media`.

Comment: @Tim I installed it from USB but from windows 8 you have to change the BIOS in the setting. It just boots straight up to Ubuntu now as I don't have windows anymore.

Comment: Trust me, the BIOS is still there... Ubuntu doesn't remove bios.

Comment: @Tim I wasn't saying that it had removed anything just that I don't know how to access them to change my boot options so as to boot from a USB. The screen where you would open the BIOS when booting up is no longer there, it wasn't there when I had windows 8 either you had to go into some settings to get to it.

Comment: Try using Del or F2 or F8 or F12 while it boots...